# equal comparison on jq variable

Tags: bash, variable, jq

I have a bash script that run a curl request and output the status via jq. I get the status as expected but when I compare the status it's always returning "non-equal" value, even if the value is equal (or seems so).

Here is the script:

```
status=( $(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic xxx==" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --data-binary "@$entry" $2/$3/_bulk_docs --silent | jq '.[0].status'))
echo $status
if [ "$status" = "409" ]
    then
      echo "Conflict"
    else
      echo "No Conflict"
fi
```

And it print 409 in the console as I expect.

I'm running this on a Windows 10 PC with Cygwin.

Thank's for further help!

Comment: Does the pipeline result in the string `409` or in `"409"`?

Comment: How could I know this? (I'm a very beginner with bash scripts)

Comment: What does `echo "<<$status>>"` return in your script? Can you tell that.

Comment: Running `echo "<<$status>>"` returns `>>409`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data has a carriage return at the end:

```
$ status=$'409\r'
$ echo "<<$status>>"
>>409
```

To remove it, use `tonumber` in `jq`:

```
status=$( curl ... | jq -r '.[0].status|tonumber' )
```

Also note that there is no need for `status` to be an array variable, as in your script, as far as I can see.

Comment: What do you mean by status is an array variable? status is inside an json object that is inside a json array, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: With `status=(...)` you create an shell array variable, but since you only put a single string into it, you don't need to create the array.  Just use `status=$(...)` instead of `status=( $(...) )`.

Comment: True! I didn't see it as I was testing stuffs, etc. Thank's for the help !